# Use simple Java mail API in Andriod's build.gradle file but get error

Tags: java, android, gradle, jakarta-mail

I am using simple Java mail API in Andriod's build.gradle file but get error.

```
**implementation group: 'org.simplejavamail', name: 'simple-java-mail', version: '6.4.3'**

Duplicate class javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.CommandInfo found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.CommandInfo$Beans found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.CommandInfo$Beans$1 found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.CommandMap found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.CommandObject found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataContentHandler found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataContentHandlerFactory found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataHandler found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataHandler$1 found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataHandlerDataSource found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataSource found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.FileDataSource found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.FileTypeMap found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap$1 found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MimeType found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MimeTypeParameterList found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap$1 found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$1 found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$2 found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$3 found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$4 found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.SecuritySupport$5 found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.URLDataSource found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
Duplicate class javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException found in modules jetified-jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar (com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:1.2.1) and jetified-jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar (jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1)
```

Comment: I think we need to see the code that causes this exception.

Comment: this is a Common Duplicate class error, I think have to exclude that package from the build.gradle file